# Add dependencies via transitive dependencies of another configuration in Gradle

Tags: gradle

I would like Gradle to compute the dependencies for a configuration by adding dependencies from dependencies loaded via a second configuration.

Example with two Gradle projects:

`dependency/build.gradle`:

```
configurations {
  other
}
dependencies {
  other "bar:artifact1:0.4"
}
```

`top/build.gradle`:

```
configurations {
  other
  modules
}
dependencies {
  modules "foo:dependency:1.0"
  other "bar:artifact2:0.1"
}
```

So the `top` project depends on `dependency` via the `modules` configuration, but I want the `other` configuration in `top` to contain both `"bar:artifact1:0.4"` and `"bar:artifact2:0.1"`.

In my concrete case, the `other` dependencies are listed in an Ivy file for each artifact. I want to collect the `other` dependencies of all the artifacts a project depends on.

This is not a multi-project build, but other projects' artifacts are loaded from a remote repository.

Is there a way to configure Gradle to include the configurations of all transitive dependencies?

Comment: In theory, you might be able to say in your configurations closure for top: `other.extendsFrom(project('dependentProjectName').configurations.other)`. Alternatively, if these dependencies are common to all your projects, you can use the allProjects closure and name your transitive configurations/dependencies in there.  If these dependencies are common to a subset of your projects, you could create a list of projects in your build script (I'll call my theoretical list 'moduleProjects'), add the desired projects, and use a closure (`moduleProjects{ }`) to name your configs/dependencies for them.

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear, but the question is not about a multi-project build. I updated the original question to clarify.